# add fixed value to column in Mysql where loading data from csv file

Tags: mysql, sql, csv

I need to enter a text value that to represent the year (will be the same for every row) in a set of data being imported from a csv file. I am getting a syntax error each time. How do I specify the text value so that it will populate the column properly?

```
Load data local infile 'C:/Users/Candace.....csv'
into table estimate(State, '2010', Population)
fields terminated by ',';
```

Comment: Can you add to your question.  Doesn't seem to jive with your comment to my answer.  Please provide way more detail and samples

Comment: I have a single column for state and population data for 2010-2016 in subsequent columns in the csv file. (State, 2010, 2011, 2012, etc.) The table needs to be pulled in stacked, (State, Year, Population) in other words, the population data in the column for 2011 would be below the 2010 data in the table being created in SQL. Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: What? This has nothing to do with your original question?! Basically you simply want to import the CSV and pivot the table?

Comment: Sorry, I'm obviously a serious newbie at this!

Comment: It's not about being a newbie, it's about being able to explain correctly what your problem is. Anybody can do it. What you wrote in your question means that the date is not part of the CSV and you want to add it manually during import. Now in the comment you are saying that the date is, in fact, part of the CSV, but dates are in columns and you want to import them as rows. If you want help you need to edit your question to clarify it. Provide a few lines of your CSV and the result your expect in your table, that will help a lot.

Comment: Ok here is my csv:
Alabama,4785492,4799918,4815960,4829479,4843214,4853875,4863300
Alaska,714031,722713,731089,736879,736705,737709,741894

I need the table to be State Year and Population. Hopefully that explains it. My apologies for not being succinct.

Answer (score 6):

Not tested, though according to [the documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) it should work:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'file.csv'
INTO TABLE estimate
(State, Population)
SET Year = 2010;
```

Relevant part from the doc:

> The SET clause can be used to supply values not derived from the input file.

Comment: Unfortunately this returns the State and population data in the same column, Year is correct and then the population column contains null values.